# Linkpoint payment gateway - charge the credit card in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, payment-processing, linkpoint

For example, now I create a invoice in future date and give the credit card details immediately. Is there any way to charge the credit card  in future for the invoice which dated in future by using Linkpoint payment gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PreAuth and PostAuth transactions. I don't know the time frame in which they are active (I guess it depends on the bank), but that should work for you and all you have to store is the order id.